# How to turn on autosubstitution in Nuxt project in VSCode?

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, nuxt.js

I install empty Nuxt project by command `npx create-nuxt-app testproject`

I select options tsconfig.json.

It created tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./*"],
      "@/*": ["./*"],
      "~~/*": ["./*"],
      "@@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", ".nuxt", "dist"]
}
```

I have installed Vetur extension.

But, when i written string like this:

```
Tutorial: () => import('@/compo')
```

Autosubstitution doesn't work.

Comment: What is `Autosubstitution`? A typescript thing? Did you mean components auto-importing?

Comment: You're maybe looking for the aliases? https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-alias#the-alias-property

Comment: @kissu autofill - phpStorm suggests me automatically, when I am writing these line. How to turn on in VSCode option like this?

Comment: @kissu It's not this. phpStorm (WebStorm) helps me by auto complete. I want use it in VSCode.

Comment: Oh, you're looking for a combo of alias + IntelliSense, I've never used/seen this kind of configuration, but you could maybe give a comment on this discussion: https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/1773 Or ask something new on Github/Discord.